# How to find where mass is leaving the system of my 1D Advection/Diffusion Simulation

Tags: python

I need help with some of my code. I have written a script to simulate advection and diffusion in 1D shoreline. There are two boundaries (one is reflective with flow going towards it and the second being a constant boundary). My main issue is that I cannot ensure that the mass (sum of concentration) within the system is constant, which it should be. I am not sure where to trobleshoot for what is causing this error. My equations are correct and i believe my boundary conditions are correct, however mass should be conserved and it is not. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

# Constants and parameters
L = 12.0  # Length in double precision
x_grid = 201  # Grid Points
sim_time = 200.0  # Simulation time in double precision
diffusion_coef = 0.01  # Diffusion coefficient (D) in double precision
adv_velocity = 0.1 # Advection Coefficient (U) in double precision
inflow_rate = 0.1  # Inflow rate in double precision
dt = 0.1  # Time step in double precision
dx = L /(x_grid - 1)  # Change in X in double precision

# Time step calculation
num_time_steps = int(sim_time / dt)

# Introduce initial beach layout
location = np.linspace(0, L, x_grid)  # Specify dtype for location

# Set shoreline to the size wanted
shoreline_amplitude = 10  # Wave amplitude in double precision
shoreline_wavelength = 6.0  # Wavelength in double precision
shoreline = shoreline_amplitude * np.cos(((2) * np.pi / shoreline_wavelength) * location + np.pi) + shoreline_amplitude
shoreline[0] = 0

# Initialize concentration array with double precision
conc = np.zeros((x_grid, num_time_steps))
conc[:, 0] = shoreline  # Set initial concentration equal to the shoreline

# Initialize an array to store the sum of concentrations for each time step
sum_concentrations = np.zeros(num_time_steps)

# Initialize arrays to track shoreline values with double precision
shoreline_0_values = np.zeros(num_time_steps)
shoreline_minus_1_values = np.zeros(num_time_steps)

# Initialize the figure for plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
max_ylim = np.max(conc)*(2)  # Initialize max_ylim to be 2 times the initial maximum

# Time-stepping loop
for t in range(1, num_time_steps):
    for i in range(1, x_grid - 1):
        # Advection-Diffusion equation
        dcdx = (conc[i + 1, t - 1] - (2) * conc[i, t - 1] + conc[i - 1, t - 1]) / dx ** (2)
        dcdt = diffusion_coef * dcdx - adv_velocity * (conc[i + 1, t - 1] - conc[i - 1, t - 1]) / ((2) * dx)
        conc[i, t] = conc[i, t - 1] + dt * dcdt
    Cnp1 = conc[x_grid - 2, t - 1] + (2) * adv_velocity * (dx / diffusion_coef) * conc[x_grid - 1, t - 1]
    dcdx = (Cnp1 - (2) * conc[x_grid - 1, t - 1] + conc[x_grid - 2, t - 1]) / dx ** (2)
    dcdt = diffusion_coef * dcdx - adv_velocity * (Cnp1 - conc[x_grid - 2, t - 1]) / ((2) * dx)
    conc[x_grid - 1, t] = conc[x_grid - 1, t - 1] + dt * dcdt

    # Track shoreline values
    shoreline_0_values[t] = shoreline[0]
    shoreline_minus_1_values[t] = shoreline[-1]

    # Calculate the maximum concentration in the updated conc array
    max_conc = np.max(conc)

    # Update max_ylim to be 2 times the current maximum concentration
    max_ylim = (2) * max_conc

    # Calculate the sum of concentrations at each time step
    sum_concentrations[t] = np.sum(conc[:, t])

    # Plotting at each time step
    if t % 10 == 0:
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(location, conc[:, t], label=f'Time = {t * dt:.2f}')
        plt.plot(location, shoreline, 'k--', label='Initial Shoreline')
        plt.axvline(x=L, color='red', linestyle='--', label='Groin')
        plt.xlabel('Location')
        plt.ylabel('Beach')
        plt.ylim([0, max_ylim])  # Set ylim to the updated max_ylim
        plt.legend()
        plt.title('Beach Advection-Diffusion Model')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.pause(0.001)

# Plot the final time step
plt.show()

# Additional plotting to track shoreline values
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(num_time_steps) * dt, shoreline_0_values, label='Shoreline[0] Values')
plt.plot(np.arange(num_time_steps) * dt, shoreline_minus_1_values, label='Shoreline[-1] Values')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Shoreline Values')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Shoreline Values over Time')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Plot mass over time
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.plot(np.arange(num_time_steps) * dt, sum_concentrations, label='Total Mass Over Time')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Total Mass')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Total Mass Over Time')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

I tried changing my boundary conditions and it still isn't working.